# Align fields in created webforms

Tags: webforms

I am new to drupal, and currently i am creating a webpage in drupal from html . i have almost completed. I have created web form for "Contact us" form, after creation it is not in proper alignment. So, my form should be look like the picture shown as below.
[image: Original Form]

So, right now it is like as below image.
[image: Currently created form]

So, please someone help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: Here is a simple example that should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204002/align-form-elements-in-css

Answer (score 0):

You can theme the webform.
Create a new file: webform-form-81.tpl.php 
(Replace the number 81 with the node ID of your webform)

Place this file in your sites theme directory (sites/all/themes/yourtheme/webform-form-81.tpl.php)

Inside this new webform-form-81.tpl.php file, insert the following code:

```
<table border="0">
<col style="width: 50%" /> <col style="width: 50%" /> </colgroup>
<tr>
    <td><?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['name']); ?><br>
    <?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['email']); ?><br>
    <?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['phone']); ?></td>

    <td><?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['notes']); ?></td>
</tr>
```

```
<?php
// Always print out the entire $form. This renders the remaining pieces of the
// form that haven't yet been rendered above (buttons, hidden elements, etc).
print drupal_render_children($form);
```

Save the file, then clear your Drupal cache.
Refresh the page with the form on it.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: You should not use tables or layout, for accessibility reasons.

Comment: @rooby I agree - These days, I would use responsive elements from a framework like Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a CSS issue. No need to rewrite the whole tpl.php. First issue regards input[type="email"] which is longer than other 2. Then there's a problem regarding textarea field wrapper. But we need form code (html), to provide proper css modifications.